# Android app crashing with Cocos2dx-js

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

my android crashes sometimes for some of the users which i am able to see google developer console.

Below is the crash log for the entire crash which i extracted out of google break pad. The crash clearly says that in the following function

> js_cocos2dx_TextFieldTTF_textFieldWithPlaceHolder

but i am not able to uderstand as to why this is happening. I am currently using cocos2dx-js v 3.5.

Any help or idea as to why this crash happens would be highly useful.

```
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/falcon_bwaca/falcon_umts:4.4.4/KXB21.14-L1.50-1/1:user/release-keys'
pid: 30910, tid: 31705, name: Thread-6337 >>> in..test <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Stack frame #00 pc 00022160 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
Stack frame #01 pc 000131b1 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
Stack frame #02 pc 000133c5 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
Stack frame #03 pc 000120fb /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #04 pc 00021a14 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
Stack frame #05 pc 00c41251 libcocos2djs.so (__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()+228): Routine js_cocos2dx_TextFieldTTF_textFieldWithPlaceHolder(JSContext*, unsigned int, JS::Value*) at jsb_cocos2dx_auto.cpp:60716
```

Comment: I guess there is some text missing in the error statement, and I can only guess: Did you create the text field with something like var t = cc.TextFieldTTF.create( ... ), then change to t = new cc.TextFieldTTF( ... ). That might help. But anyway: get the latest version 3.9. A lot of bugs were fixed.

Comment: thanks a lot michael

Comment: Did it work? If so, was it the "new"-trick or the 3.9 version? I would like to make an answer out of it, so that others find it easier.

Comment: so the challenge is that this is not something happens always.. while the app is in production some users face it. I was able to extract this info from the google breakpad info which google provides. I will only come to know wether it fixed or not once the app goes live. Will update the answer when i have something conclusive on the same